# Sending json file to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress

I am trying to send a json file to a server url. I am not getting any error but when I enter in the url, it is empty.

```
$('#form-output code').html(JSON.stringify(params, undefined, 4));
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://netfish.xyz/wp- 
content/uploads/2018/05/archivo.json";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
 }
};
var data = JSON.stringify(params, undefined, 4);
console.log('eeeeee');
console.log(data);
xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: This is an actual JSON file, right? Why are you POSTing to it?

Comment: You can't directly write some data to a server with AJAX, you need some server-side code to write the passed data to a file.

Comment: jQuery make what you're doing in several lines in one, Why don't you use library Ajax method ?

Comment: @Teemu can you show me an example of a server side code for doing this? Thank you

Comment: @JoseRojas which method?

Comment: @JonVelasco take a look http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/